# SP13: Blank Space on Pages

Tags: 2013, development, javascript, master-page, custom-masterpage

I am recently changed the master page to have the page content to be centered. My focus for the centering was on the home page that successfully centered.  However, navigating to the other pages the format is distorted. See image below for an example.  The document library has moved down to the bottom of the page creating a huge space.  I am assuming the `s4-bodycontainer` or `<div class="wrapper">` is creating the issue.  Find below the specific code that I believe is causing this space.  The issue is that if I make any changes it causes the home page centering to be altered.

```
<div id="s4-workspace" style="height: 450px; margin: 0 auto; padding-left: 250px; width: 1550px"> 
<div class="wrapper"> <div id="s4-bodycontainer"><div class="push ms-dialogHidden"></div><div class="footer ms-dialogHiddencenterMargin"></div>
```

Has anyone experienced this issue?  Do I change the style height and/or margin sizes?
Thanks for any assistance?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your 'Home' and 'Document Library' don't have enough space to sit. Did you analysed the rendered HTML content? Better use F12 Developer Tools. -Karu.